# How to lower iPhone/iPad brightness?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How do I lower the brightness further than the limitations on the iPhone / iPad?

Answer (score 0):

To lower brightness lower than the limit:

> Settings app > General > Accessibility > Zoom:
>
> Set Zoom Region > "Full Screen Zoom"
>
> Set Zoom Filter > "Low Light"
>
> Set Maximum Zoom Level all the way to the right (The highest value)

Go back to Accessibility:

> Settings app > General > Accessibility > Accessibility Shortcut:
>
> Set "Triple-Click The Home Button For" > Zoom

To Test: Triple click the home button and the screen will go darker.

Comment: Seems a rather convoluted method for something that's on the Control Centre anyway.